# Laravel response ids change when response is json but when dumping the data the ids are there

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

i am trying to use ajax request in Laravel which searches records based on select2 input. Now i am transforming that data once i've fetched it, just to encrypt the ids. Here's how i get the records and transform their ids to encrypt.

```
    public function autocompletePedigree($subdomain, $type = null)
    {

        $q = request()->get('q');

        $sex = NULL;
        if (!is_null($type)) {
            $sex = $this->sexesRepository->make()->where('name', $type)->first(['id'])->id;
        }

        $results = $this->dogsRepository->search($q, $sex);

        $results->getCollection()->transform(function ($value) {
            $value->id = encrypt($value->id);
            return $value;
        });

        return $results;
    }
```

Now the results contain a dog name and id and when i use `dd($results)` the ids are transformed and correct here's an example

```
#attributes: array:2 [▼
  "id" => "eyJpdiI6IlN5YXdzT3hReEc2bnczRGM5YzV1eGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZ0NpaTRGWjNmS1ZEQjVZcGFZeWJRdz09IiwibWFjIjoiMThmNmQ5YmE5ZDI1MDg4OTZhMmExMTlmNzM0ZGU3ZDRhNzg0OGFhNzM2OTViYzVkN2QxZTUzMzMwMWY4ZDdhYiJ9"
  "text" => "Dog name"
]
```

But when i switch to JSON using `return response()->json($results)` it returns this

```
"data":[
  {
    "id":0,
    "text":"Dog name"
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "text":"Doggy name"
  }
```

I cant understand why its turning ids into 0. Is this some kind of a JSON sanitization process? Can someone please help me to keep the encrypted ids in JSON response?

Comment: Can you share the model too?

Comment: @petersowah the model and everything else is correct i can assure you. This only occurs when i am trying to switch to json

Comment: Share model, please, it seems you have some rules how to convert to json

Comment: Just added the entire model

Comment: You'll probably need to show the contents of `BBAfrica\Clubs\Extensions\Model` too, as you're extending that class instead of the default Model (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`)

Comment: added that and the model that extends it too

Comment: Fixed the problem guys, anyways thanks for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little bit of digging i found out that its been automatically casted into integer which caused a little bit of stir. So i fixed the issue by adding `public $incrementing = false;` to `Dogs` Model

Answer (score 1):

For everyone else who's curious (like me) on why that is happening:

He is changing the type of his model's primary key. When he (or in this case the `JsonResponse`) calls `toJson()` on the model, it tries to cast that primary key (which was manually changed to `string`) back to it's original value (`int`) and since `(int) "eyJpdiI6IlN ..."` equals `0` his key is `0` too.

That happens because the primary key is actually [added to the `$casts` property](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L1028) of the model:

```
public function getCasts()
{
    if ($this->getIncrementing()) {
        return array_merge([$this->getKeyName() => $this->getKeyType()], $this->casts);
    }

    return $this->casts;
}
```

... and the properties are casted when the model gets serialised to an array (and later on to JSON).